# Array of functions with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I am currently working on an array of functions and want to get the right function back with a condition.

Here is my code **:**

```
  {'key':'a', 'function':func_a},
  {'key':'b', 'function':func_b},
  {'key':'c', 'function':func_c},
  {'key':'d', 'function':func_d}
];

const term = 'b';

const funcToDo = for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (term === a[i].key) {
      return a[i].function
    }
  }

const shouldIDoIt = true;
shouldIDoIt === true ? functToDo() : null;
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? `const funcToDo = for (` is obviously not allowed, but what is stopping you from writing a function for finding the correct element in the array?

Comment: `const funcToDo = for (...)` - Where did you found that syntax?

Comment: _"i am currently working on a array of functions..."_ - Why that overly complex setup? -> `const functions = { "a": func_a, "b": func_b, ... } const funcToDo = functions[term]; ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to then return from that array an Object which matches a specific property value

```js
const find = (arr, k, v) => arr.find(ob => ob[k] === v);

const func_a = () => console.log("aaa!");
const func_b = () => console.log("bbb!");
const func_c = () => console.log("ccc!");

const arrFn = [
  {key: "a", function: func_a},
  {key: "b", function: func_b},
  {key: "c", function: func_c},
];

const funcToDo = find(arrFn, "key", "b")?.function;
const shouldIDoIt = true;

funcToDo && shouldIDoIt && funcToDo();
```